# QTP AOM Model Intellience Not Working

Tags: vbscript, com, automation, qtp

I want to use QTP AOM(Automation Object Model) using vbscript. I use VbsEdit to develop this script but I did not get any intellience from this editor even I also try this from excel developer window. There also intellence assistance is not available.

I need this because if it is not appear then how can I know the available(open) methods and properties from this COM object.

I have also another question that we write this below line to instantiate a QTP object using vbs

```
CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
```

For excel

```
CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

How can I know the COM objects name means can I list down all COM object name programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions here.

#### Why don't you get intelisense for the QTP object in the IDE you're using (VBSEdit)

Intelisense is a feature of the IDE, you should tag this question VBSEdit, not QTP

#### Where can I get a list of all the COM objects in the system?

When you use `CreateObject` you're specifying a [ProgID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProgID) which is a  string identifyier for a COM class (slightly more human readable than a [CLSID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424.aspx). COM uses the registry to maintain its `Prog` and `Cls` `ID`s, you can find the ProgId's under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` registry hive (look for keys with a child `CLSID` key).